# How to delete data in DMVs( system tables) in Microsoft Parallel Datawarehouse

Tags: sql-server, parallel-data-warehouse

I need to delete some of the data in a system table. Is there anything that I can do?

Comment: What possible reason could you have for that?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot delete data from DMVs, nor alter results from DMFs since they are collecting the data from sql server resource table which is unavailable to the user.

The only way to reset the data is to restart/shutdown sql server service

Comment: What if I have admin rights?
PS : I am working as a Database administrator

Comment: No its not about permissions. Pre SQL Server 2005, there were no DMVs/DMFs and DBAs and all the tables were placed in master DB. Since DBAs had access to the master DB, they could code against these system tables(etc sysprocesses) and put system in danger.Since 2005 Microsoft created "resource" database containing these tables and views which are hidden from users/DBAs completely. There are some workaround how to access to it which you will have to explore more into it